# How to generate alpha number values from a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using the below in my stored procedure to create a 8 digit password and return it as output.

```
select @AuthKey = @AuthKey + char(n) from
(
    select top 8 number as n from master.. spt_values
    where type= 'p' and number between 48 and 57
    order by newid()
) as t
```

But i want the output as alpha numeric value, instead of just numeric value. How can i get it ?

Comment: Okay its done... WHERE TYPE='p' and (number between 48 and 57 or number between 65 and 90)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where that *(the use of spt_values)* falls on the stylish vs. sneaky scale... but I kindof like it !

Comment: @Anuya As [this blog post notes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." so I would say move your comment to an answer and then accept it. This will also stop this question from showing up on the unanswered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anuya -- this is a very clever way to randomize values, using `order by newid()`.  You can also use lowercase characters, if your passwords are case sensitive:

```
declare @AuthKey varchar(255)
set @AuthKey = ''
select @AuthKey = @AuthKey + char(n) from
(
    select top 8 number as n 
    from master..spt_values
    where type= 'p' and (
            (number between 48 and 57)  -- numbers
      or    (number between 65 and 90)  -- uppercase letters
      or    (number between 97 and 122) -- lowercase letters
    )
    order by newid()
) as t 
print @AuthKey
```

Using a slightly different approach, you could include a specific character set, including symbols:

```
declare @AuthKey varchar(255), @chars varchar(255), @len int
set @AuthKey = ''
set @chars = '012345ACDFGIJKLMSTXYZ_-#@!'
set @len = len(@chars)

select @AuthKey = @AuthKey + chr.c
from (
    select substring(@chars, num.n, 1) as c
    from (
        select top 8 number as n
        from master..spt_values
        where type='p' and (number between 1 and @len)
        order by newid()
    ) as num
) as chr
print @AuthKey
```

Of course this only includes any given character one time.  Still it is a very clever way of generating passwords.  Kudos!

Edit:
If you want to have the chance of having doubles, you can do it like this :

```
declare @AuthKey varchar(255), @chars varchar(255), @len int
set @AuthKey = ''
set @chars = '012345ACDFGIJKLMSTXYZ_-#@!'
set @len = len(@chars)

SELECT TOP 8 @AuthKey = @AuthKey + SubString(@chars, 1 + Convert(int, ABS(BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID())) % @len), 1)
  FROM master..spt_values
```

(will be slightly faster too as the query doesn't require sorting spt_values.